# If Cycle in R Shiny

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a simple If Cycle in R Shiny but I am founding some issues. I want to create a variable, in this case m, according to what the user inputs. Here there is the code:

```
if(input$city=="Enter Text..."){


 m<-reactive({leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite) %>%
  addPolylines(data = trips(),
               lng = ~V1, 
               lat = ~V2,weight=1,color="purple") %>%
addCircles(lng = geocode(input$city)$lon, lat = geocode(input$city)$lat, weight = 5,
          radius =input$radius, popup = input$city, color="blue",fillOpacity = 0)
})

} else {

m<-reactive({leaflet() %>% 
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite) %>%
    addPolylines(data = trips(),
                 lng = ~V1, 
                 lat = ~V2,weight=1,color="purple")
})
}
```

In doing this I get an error that says that I am trying to do something outside a reactive environment, but the variable m is defined as reactive. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`input$city` is indeed a reactive element which needs to be use in a reactive environment.
Just add the if statement inside of your `reactive()` function. And it will make the code clearer since the beginning of the `leaflet` construction is the same.

```
 m<-reactive({leaflet() %>% 
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite) %>%
    addPolylines(data = trips(),
                 lng = ~V1, 
                 lat = ~V2,weight=1,color="purple") %>%
    {if(input$city=="Enter Text..."){
          addCircles(., lng = geocode(input$city)$lon, 
          lat = geocode(input$city)$lat, weight = 5,
          radius =input$radius, popup = input$city, 
          color="blue",fillOpacity = 0)
     } else {.}
    }
})
```

By using `addCircles(.,`, you get the chaining into the if statement and with `else {.}`, you just return the previous element, without adding the `addCircles` function.

Comment: It looks like it has solved the previous issue, however, now it returns "argument map is missing with no default". Have you got any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot the point in `addCircles` to get the chaining in the if statement. Try to provide a reproducible example next time :)

Comment: I don't understand you you mean, why is this not reproducible?

Comment: Your code can't be run. For a Shiny app for example, you need the ui.R and the server.R